# drawing torus in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

Im using the equation from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108998/parametric-equations-for-a-2-torus) to draw a torus. My `c=3.7` and `a=0.5`. I've played a lot with these values but always getting a rather misshapen torus (way too tall).

Matlab command:

```
ezmesh('(3.7+0.5*cos(v))*cos(u)','(3.7+ 0.5*cos(v))*sin(u)','0.5*sin(v)',[0,2*pi,0,2*pi])
```

And a screenshot of what im getting.

[image]

How can I tweak it so it looks like a "nice" donut?? Is there a problem with the equation itself ?

Comment: Have you tried `axis equal`? Your image is just distorting because the z axis scale is so much smaller than the other two

Comment: @Dan looks more like an apple than a torus (the hole got smaller)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Dan suggested, the torus looks right, but if you check to the X,Y,ans Z axis you can notice that you dont have them  in the same scale. `Axis equal` will make the scale to be equal in all the coordinates

Comment: bingo, surprised it doesnt scale axis automatically!

Comment: @PeterQ It scales the axes to fill as much of the window as possible rather than to preserve the spatial equality of the axes as in most case you'll be plotting totally different dimensions anyways

Comment: Shouldn't this answer have been left for @Dan to give?

Comment: Shouldn't @Dan have "answered" the question vs just posting a comment?